# Cannot get autoinstall 22.04 to boot

Tags: boot, 22.04, autoinstall

Hello I am trying to make an ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall usb

20.04 boots fine but I cannot get 22.04 going.

I am running this on a headless & keyboardless server as my cat chewed through my keyboard cable

In the grub I have changed the line to many things now

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz   quiet   autoinstall   ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/  ---

linux   /casper/vmlinuz   quiet   autoinstall   ---

linux   /casper/vmlinuz   quiet   autoinstall   ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud/  ---

linux   /casper/vmlinuz   autoinstall   quiet   ---
```

My user-data file is

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntusrv
    password: "REDACTED"
    username: REDACTED
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
    authorized-keys:
      - "ssh-rsa REDACTED"
    allow-pw: no
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

The iso command is

> xorriso -as mkisofs -r -V "ubuntu-22-04-autoinstall" -J
> -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -input-charset utf-8 -eltorito-alt-boot -b bootpart/eltorito_img1_bios.img -no-emul-boot -o ../installer22.04.iso .

Thanks in advance here's hoping. I've been trying this for days

EDIT...

So I managed to get the installer going but now it seems to be ignoring grub.cfg. It ignores the timeout and the extra menu item.

Comment: Please provide additional information about how you got the installer going in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that startup disk creator wasn't seeing the iso I was creating.

I fixed by annoyingly borrowing a windows machine and putting the iso to the usb with rufus. I am sure I could have done that with an ubuntu tool but I had wasted so long on this